# Django. Не удается отправить письмо с вложением

Tags: django

Файл по пути filename не сохраняется, а письмо приходит, но без вложения.

Форма:

```
<form action="/send_resume" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="ФИО">
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
  <input type="file" name="file" accept=".pdf" required>

  <button>Отправить резюме</button>
</form>
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
@require_POST
def send_resume(request):
    form = ResumeForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    print(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        send_mail('mail/resume.html', {
            'resume': form.cleaned_data
        })
        return JsonResponse({'result' : 'ok'})
    else:
        print(form.errors)
        return JsonResponse({'error' : form.errors})
```

mail.py:

```
def send_mail(template, context=None,
              from_email=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL):

    subject, content = render_message(template, context)
    resume_email = Career.objects.values_list('id', flat=True).get(id=1)

    msg = EmailMessage('Proxima Resume', content, from_email, to=['*@gmail.com'])
    if context['resume']['file']:
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        try:
            filename = fs.save(context['resume']['file'].name, context['resume']['file'])
            msg.attach(context['resume']['file'].name, fs.open(filename).read(), context['resume']['file'].content_type)
        except:
            pass
    msg.content_subtype = 'html'
    msg.send()
```

Comment: Ну, базовая логика подсказывает мне в первую очередь убрать `except: pass` и посмотреть, что за ошибка там возникает

Comment: что там написать?

Comment: Не написать, а убрать `except: pass` чтобы посмотреть, что за ошибка там возникает

Comment: по-моему в Python try без except не используется. Не запускает проект - IndentationError: unexpected unindent

Comment: Вот и try тоже уберите, и лишний indent тоже уберите

Comment: Так даже письмо не приходит

Comment: Ну так а ошибка-то какая-нибудь появилась? Пофиг на письмо, нужен текст ошибки

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133812/discussion-between-mynick-and-andreymal).